# How to set border of each tab in tabhost

Tags: android

I am using `tabhost`. I have two tabs in that. I can able to set border for `tabwidget`. But I don't know how to set border for each tab.

> I tried to get current tab and convert the view as textview and had
>   set border but It was looking like **view is wrapped,so the border
>   encloses the tab name with no gap** .I don't know how to add padding
>   to make it as `match_parent`.

Here is my code,

```
    int tab = TabHostWindow.getCurrentTab();
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) TabHostWindow.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabdes));
```

> Guide me please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a custom item view for tab . [This](https://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/smartpad/2/) link may help .